# OData in .NET 5 - converting DateTime to Edm.Date breaks skip token generation

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, odata, paging

When DataTime field is exposed via OData in .NET 5 Web API, it has both Date and Time components. We are mainly using it for exposing Dates so there is now a requirement to format the cumbersome yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss+timezone to just the date part yyyy-MM-dd. For this I've found, that OData support converting DateTime to Edm.Date with this exact reason behind.

Following this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/date-timeofday-with-entity-framework) I can do the conversion in two ways:

1. decorate the DateTime property in the result entity DTO with Column attribute:

```
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
```

2. configure the date property in the model configuration by adding "AsDate()":

```
Builder.EntitySet<ResultDto>("ExampleDataSet").EntityType
  .HasKey(o => o.Id)
  .Property(c => c.StartDate).AsDate();
```

It works quite well and I get what I need, but the problem starts when the DateTime property is a key or a part of the key. In that case:

1. the Column attribute is ignored and the date format doesn't change.
2. If configuration is changed, an exception is  thrown at the serialization and in the results instead of getting the nextLink with the skip token, I get an exception with the message *"The type 'System.DateTime' is not supported when converting to a URI literal."*

I tried to override DefaultSkipTokenHandler class with my own implementation, but the exception happens in the GenerateNextPagLink method which means I have to write my own NextLink Generator. Before I try doing that, I want to check, that I have not messed up somewhere else or am trying to achieve things in a backwards way. If not, is this a bug in the OData library?

Libraries used:

- Microsoft.OData.Core v7.9.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning.ApiExplorer v5.0.0

Comment: This is unsupported as yet in Key implementation, I would recommend against using Edm.Date as part of the key for now. You should try posting on the [GitHub: AspNetCoreOData](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData) issues forum